# Making a fixed image recovered by a container

Tags: html, css

I saw some very cool artistic designs in CSS and something just blew up my mind. It was a fixed image down the navbar which was not moving when scrolling but the div with text in was covering it and making it disappear. I tried this

```html
<img class="frontpic" src="firstpicRenewables.jpeg" >
    <div class="listconteneur">
      <div class="list1"><h4>Solar</h4></div>
      <div class="list2"><h4>Water</h4></div>
      <div class="list3"><h4>Innovation</h4></div>
    </div>
```

```css
.frontpic
{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}

.listconteneur
{
  margin-top: 30%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Unfortunatly it didn't work at all... the image was fixed but acting like she didn't care about the z-index < then the div class listconteneur one. So if you can get me a little of help it will be appreciated a lot ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index: -1;` on `.frontpic`

```css
.frontpic
{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}

.listconteneur
{
  margin-top: 30%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img class="frontpic" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmymodernmet.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F03%2Fgabrielius-khiterer-stray-cats-8.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" >
    <div class="listconteneur">
      <div class="list1"><h4>Solar</h4></div>
      <div class="list2"><h4>Water</h4></div>
      <div class="list3"><h4>Innovation</h4></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank a lot for your help and your time !